How to open folder in explorer onclick of button in Electron?
How do I open a folder in explorer onclick of a button in my electronjs application? I got it to work by making it where it is executed at program start in the main. But id i make it a function and call in it with onclick from HTML button it doesn't work. Ive tried form renderer, main, and preload. I'm pretty knew to electron and node, so i have a feeling that maybe I'm not understanding the processes correctly?
default.html
<button name="SystemMenu-Button" id="SystemMenu-Button" class="SystemMenu-Button" onclick="openDocuments()">
    Documents
    <i name="SystemMenu-ButtonIcon" id="SystemMenu-ButtonIcon" class="fa-solid fa-folder-open fa-fw"></i>
</button>

default.main.js - works but not what I need
const { app, BrowserWindow, shell } = require('electron');
const path = require('node:path');
const documentsPath = 'E:/';

shell.openPath(documentsPath);

default.main.js - wont work but it need it to
const { app, BrowserWindow, shell } = require('electron');
const path = require('node:path');
const documentsPath = 'E:/';

function openDocuments() {
    shell.openPath(documentsPath);
}


This question is similar to: Add a button to open "File Explorer". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As you're using Windows based system I'll recommend the following:
import child_process from 'node:child_process';

const WindowsDocumentsPath = '%HomeDrive%' + '%HomePath%' + '/Documents';

child_process.exec(`start ${WindowsDocumentsPath}`);

This will instance a new child process for your console (cmd/powershell) and then just single call the start command from your console.
Note that in Windows you can use the wildcard variables to access common dynamic locations:
%AppData%/AppName points to where your electron browser data is stored.
%HomeDrive%%HomePath%/Documents points to the current user My Documents directory (by default, if not changed).
%Public% points to the windows public user directory (usually C:\Users\Public.
PS.: Beware at what user your electron is running under... If you shift-click and Run as... your electron, then even if you're under your user credentials, the electron will be at the credentials you selected it to run as (you must enter the password of the selected user, even the Administrator). In this case, the code above would open the documents directory of the selected user, not the active user's.

I was trying to word it in a way that it would open any folder i need. The original code is to open a documents folder but not the user docs, but a documents folder on an external hard drive.

How do i call that when i need to? Do i wrap the whole thing in a function? Im Pretty new to all this. Or just the last line? Does this go in main or renderer? I can simply replace the path with whatever i need to right?

shell.openPath(documentsPath); This works just like i need it to. It just wont work when i put it in a function so i can call it onclick of a button.

I would have to do that ICP thing to use that method huh? Becuase its a main process but it has to be called from render to use it.

@DUSTINANGELETTI, hmm.. Your function is defined in the node context while the onclick is called on the browser context?If so, then you need to expose your openDocuments function in the node context to the browser context. You can do that through routing. Yet, Electron has a configuration that exposes the node context to the browser context. Electron documentation contains a very good guide to make that happen.
